# How to clear textboxes after update method

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

I have 3 textboxes, one checkbox, listview and 3 buttons. Now the thextboxes and a checkbox are bound to property "User" in ManageUsersViewModel. ListView have its selected item bound to property "SelectedUser". Buttons are named as "Add", "Edit", "Save". Every button is bound to it's own command. The command for "Add" button works fine. When I click on it I call a method from WCF service which inserts new user to database. When i select some row in listview, and click on button "Edit" checkbox and textboxes are filled with values that i selected. Now i can change the values and save changes by clicking on button "Save". The problem is, i can not add new user again after this process. When I try to add new user, the values i have entered into textboxes also changes the value that I previously changed. Bassicly I cant do the add function again, after update function until i restart the window. Also I want my textboxes, and checkbox to get cleared after add or update function. Here is my code:

**ManageUsersViewModel**

```
class ManageUsersViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   #region Constructor

    private ServiceReference1.tblUser user;
    public ServiceReference1.tblUser User    
    {
        get
        {
            return user;
        }
        set
        {
            user = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("User");
        }
    }

    private ServiceReference1.tblUser selectedUser;
    public ServiceReference1.tblUser SelectedUser
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedUser;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedUser = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.tblUser> users;
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.tblUser> Users     // Property "Service"
    {
        get
        {
            return users;
        }
        set
        {
            users = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Users");
        }
    }

    public ManageUsersViewModel()
    {
    }   // Konstruktor

    #endregion

    public ICommand _addUser;
    public ICommand addUser 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addUser == null)
            {
                _addUser = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {                            
                        Service1Client wcf = new Service1Client();
                        wcf.AddUser(User);
                        Users.Add(User);
                        wcf.Close();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }

            return _addUser;
        }
    }

 public ICommand _btnEditUser;
    public ICommand btnEditUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (_btnEditUser == null)
            {
                _btnEditUser = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        User = SelectedUser;

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }

            return _btnEditUser;
        }
    }

    public ICommand _btnUpdateUser;
    public ICommand btnUpdateUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (_btnUpdateUser == null)
            {
                _btnUpdateUser = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Service1Client wcf = new Service1Client();
                        wcf.updateUser(SelectedUser);
                        wcf.Close();                           


                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }

            return _btnUpdateUser;
        }
    }
}
```

**ManageUsers.xaml**

```
<TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,12,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" BorderBrush="#89000000" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" TabIndex="0" Text="{Binding Path=User.Name}" />
    <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,43,0,0" Name="txtNewUsername" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" BorderBrush="#89000000" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" TabIndex="1" Text="{Binding Path=User.Username}" />
    <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,74,0,0" Name="txtPassword" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" BorderBrush="#89000000" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" TabIndex="2" Text="{Binding Path=User.Password}" />
    <Button Content="Dodaj" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,12,0,0" Name="btnAddUser" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" BorderBrush="Black" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding addUser}" />
    <Button Content="Izmeni" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="381,152,0,0" Name="btnEditUser" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" BorderBrush="Black" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Command="{Binding btnEditUser}" />
    <Button BorderBrush="Black" Content="Sačuvaj" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsDefault="True" Margin="361,12,0,0" Name="btnUpdateUser" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" Visibility="Visible" Command="{Binding btnUpdateUser}"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Administrator" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,110,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#89000000" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" TabIndex="3" IsChecked="{Binding User.IsAdmin}" />
    <ListView SelectionMode="Single" Height="204" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,152,0,0" Name="lvUsers" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="368" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedUser}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you adduser command to set the user to a new one:

That should clear the fields and allow creating a new user.

```
public ICommand addUser 
{
    get
    {
        if (_addUser == null)
        {
            _addUser = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
            {
                try
                {                            
                    Service1Client wcf = new Service1Client();
                    wcf.AddUser(User);
                    Users.Add(User);
                    wcf.Close();
                    this.User = new User();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                }
            });
        }

        return _addUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I lost a couple of days for this and it's only one line of the code...

Answer (score 1):

After Add and update process completed, set User and SelectedUser property as new instance.
e.g 
if User is object of ClSUser class then

```
User=new ClSUser();
```

so on for SelectedUser.